# return only tables from query, not views

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I write to return only tables that exist in a DB with the column name `'employee_no'` so atm I can say

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%employee_no'
```

but this also returns views, I only want actual tables.

something like ?

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%employee_no' and WHERE TYPE = 'U'
```

?

Answer (score 3):

You can check `TABLES.TABLE_TYPE`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c JOIN
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
     ON c.table_name = t.table_name AND
        c.table_schema = t.table_schema
WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME like '%employee_no' AND
      t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```